# How to change a char in a string in C++

Tags: c++, string

I was trying to solve this problem but I think I am not doing the string handling part right.
The problem is given a string (let's say "abc") write out all upper and lower case combinations of this string.

My approach was to modify binary counter method.

So here's my implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

#define LOWER_CASE_DIFF 'a'-'A'

using namespace std;

void changeSeq(string &in, int amount) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < amount && (int)in[i] < 'a') {
        in[i] += LOWER_CASE_DIFF;
        i++;
    }
    if (i < amount) {
        in[i] -= LOWER_CASE_DIFF;
    }
    cout << in << endl;
}
int main() {
    string input = "abc";
    int diff = 'a' - 'A'; //a is always bigger than A in ASCII
    int comb = (int)pow(2,(float)input.length());
    for (int i = 1; i <= comb; i++) {
        changeSeq(input, i);    
    }


    return 0;
}
```

I am getting this runtime error:

```
/usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/basic_string.h:707: typename _Alloc::rebind<_CharT>::other::reference std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator[](typename _Alloc::rebind<_CharT>::other::size_type) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]: Assertion '__pos < size()' failed.

Disallowed system call: SYS_kill
```

So how can I change one character at a time? Is strings behaviour in C++ similar to `const char* str = "abc"` in C, where array of characters are stored in constants?

Comment: You can change the contents of the string, but I think your problem is with indexing - i.e. accessing `input[6]` is not valid if the string is less than 6 characters long. Did you at least debug to see where it breaks?

Comment: `(int)pow(2,(float)input.length())` is a very bad idea. Floating-point numbers are not exact, so it is possible that `pow(2, 3) == 7.99999` and thus `(int)pow(2, 3) == 7`...

Comment: Interesting, it works for me: http://ideone.com/VRLPNI

Comment: Furthermore, it seems to me that you are looking for **permutations** of the string. There are `n!` of those, and not `2 ^ n`.

Comment: @H2CO3 judging from his `changeSeq` it seems as if he just wants ABC AbC not BCA BaC .. so 2^n seems right

Comment: @SarpKaya you could write `1 << input.length()` instead of the overly complicated `(int)pow(2,(float)input.length());`

Comment: @LuchianGrigore,

Thanks, actually you are right. I have a problem with my loop, it should start from 0 and not include the last character.
As this is directly taken from the binary counter I am getting that problem.

Comment: @claptrap, most people do not like using bitwise operators as it decreases readability. I still would like to use `pow()`, is there a less complicated way to do it?

Comment: you find `(int)pow(2,(float)input.length());` more readable than `1 << input.length()` ? see my suggestion below

Comment: Well it's casting. Also more generic and not only limited to 2.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
  string s = "ABC";
  int comb = 1 << s.length();
  for (int i = 0; i < comb; ++i) // 0000 0001 0010 ... 1000
  {
    for ( size_t j = 0; j < s.length(); ++j )
    {
      if ( i & (1 << j) )
      { 
        s[j] = tolower(s[j]); 
      }
      else
      { 
        s[j] = toupper(s[j]); 
      }
    }
    cout << s << endl;
  }
```

probably would be better to include a

```
bool testbit(int value, int bit)
{
  return value & (1 << bit);
}
```

to make the code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `string` header

```
#include <string>
```

Other then that, it seems to be working fine in VS2013

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over-complicating thing when trying to compute the number of possible outputs; maybe this'll help:

```
for(i=0;i<input.length();i++)
{
 for(j=0;j<input.length();j++)
 {
  printString(input);
  changeCase(input[j]);
 }
 printString(input);
 changeCase(input[i]);
}
```